# How to get real IP address bypassing hosts file on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, cpprest-sdk

I added a host-ip mapping in my C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
192.168.1.105 www.facebook.com
```

I tried both getaddrinfo and DnsQuery, neither works.

The DsnQuery code is from [this example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/831226).
The result is:

> The IP address of the host www.facebook.com is 192.168.1.105

However, the command 'nslookup' works fine:

> C:\Users\abc>nslookup www.facebook.com
>
> 服务器:  public1.114dns.com
>
> Address:  114.114.114.114
>
> 非权威应答:
>
> 名称:    www.facebook.com
>
> Addresses:  200:2:2e52:ae44::
>
> ```
>       93.46.8.89
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I thought DNS_QUERY_BYPASS_CACHE might do the job. But actually **DNS_QUERY_NO_HOSTS_FILE** should be used.